# How to convert oracle RAW data type (saved as string) to java String?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a string stored in RAW data type in oracle and want to convert it into a java String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following Spring JPA Repository code.**
@Query(value = "select cryptFun.encrypt(:str) from dual", nativeQuery = true)
public byte[] findEncryptedToken(@Param("str") String token);

**cryptFun.encrypt(str) function in the above query returns RAW data type.**

Below is the Java conversion:

```
byte[] rawDataTypeBytes = repository.findEncryptedStr("1111111111111111");
String token = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rawDataTypeBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rawtohex` in your sql query itself.
Example :  `SELCECT RAWTOHEX(SOME_ID) FROM TABLE`

You can even extract your data as raw only and at API level convert it to string. When I say API level, I mean if you are using jdbc , spring-jdbc , spring data etc.